# Dynamically appending text to XML with C#

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

I want to generate the XML as shown below.

I generated the elements of it, but now I am struggling to append the text dynamically to it.

Can any one help me to do as shown above.

[image: XML]

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code you already have?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem right, this will help:

```
        XmlElement node = doc.CreateElement("H_SENDER");
        node.InnerText = "BROYHILL ONLINE";
```